# Get user thumbs from YouTube comments feed?

Tags: xml, youtube, youtube-api, feed

Does anyone know if it's possible to get user thumbnail URIs in YouTube video comment feeds, e.g.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/3bfTgL4iI60/comments?max-results=50

I found [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial?hl=es) which suggests you can stipulate what fields you want. Works if you append `fields=entry`, for example, but the second example mentioned, which appears to promise what I'm after, generates an error: `&fields=entry(media:group)`, saying 'media' is an unknown alias.

Note I realise you can load a separate feed to get user thumb, but I'm trying to do it in one.

The feed does contain the commenter's username, but as far as I know there's no way to take this and generate the thumbnail. Google user thumb SRCs don't seem to be based on username.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am currently using which is a fixed YouTube url.

```
<img src="https://i1.ytimg.com/i/USER_ID/1.jpg" width="40" height="40">
```

The only problem with this is that people are now using Google accounts as YouTube accounts.
So if they do, their picture will be the default YouTube picture.

I would sagest if that is a problem, doing what I will be doing which is to make an api call for the pic inside your loop script when getting your comments. If you look in the XML that you get from your call, it is in

```
<media:thumbnail url='http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/s88-c-k/photo.jpg'/>
```

Unfortunatly with Google pictures, the URL's are never the same. So a call must be made.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Yeah I know I can make a separate API call to get the pic, just I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Thought I would let you know. I put the script in for grabbing the url for the thumbnail, and it makes it 13 times slower. So will not use it for now myself till I can find a better way.